# Barkhausen stability criterion and poles location in s domain

Tags: control-system, transfer-function, stability, laplace-transform

For studying stability, I am actually working with 2 methods :

Here is the Barkhausen stability criterion :

The loop gain is equal to unity in absolute magnitude, that is,

$$|\beta A|= 1 $$

and the phase shift around the loop is zero or an integer multiple of 2π:

$$\angle{\beta A} = 2\pi n, n \in 0,1,2... $$

Barkhausen's criterion is a necessary condition for oscillation but not a sufficient condition: some circuits satisfy the criterion but do not oscillate

Here is what the pole zero plot says :

In order for a linear system to be stable, all of its poles must have negative real parts,that is they must all lie within the left-half of the s-plane. An “unstable”pole, lying in the right half of the s-plane, generates a component in the system homogeneous response that increases without bound from any finite initial conditions. A system having one or more poles lying on the imaginary axis of the s-plane has non-decaying oscillatory components in its homogeneous response, and is defined to be marginally stable.

One of the methods is more precise than the other but there is probably a link between the both. As the pole zero plot is made from the Laplace theory, I would say that the barkhausen stability criterion is coming from Laplace as Laplace is older than Barkausen.

Does anyone know how to make the link ?

Comment: To be precise: Barkhausens criterion is just a necessary condition for oscillation - it is NOT a general stability criterion (like Nyquists criterion).